# Generate and store hypernyms for all words in a hashmap

Tags: java, machine-learning, natural-language-processing

I have a system which reads in a clause in the form of a prolog "fact", i.e. `'is'('a sentence', 'this').`. I want to generalize this up into higher-order classes and types, rather than just single words. At this juncture, one things I'm going to try out, as a sort of initial step, is the just generate all the hypernyms associated with that word and store them, possibly, alongside their root in the hashmap (where I'm currently storing sentences). What would be the best way to do that?

Eventually the subject and objects get cross-referenced to check for identical entities, and subsequently generating learned "rules" through inference, i.e. `'contains'('vitamin c', 'oranges').`, `'prevents'('scurvy', 'vitamin c').` would yield the output "rule" `'prevents'('scurvy', 'oranges').`

(FYI) I've incorporated WordNet and also the Java WordNet Interface

This is the main method:

```
public class lets_go 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        MITJavaWordNetInterface wordnet_interface = new MITJavaWordNetInterface();

        Ontology ontology = new Ontology();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'\\('(.*?)',\\s*'(.*?)'\\)\\.");
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
            if( m.matches() ) 
            {
                String verb    = m.group(1);
                String object  = m.group(2);
                String subject = m.group(3);
                ontology.addSentence( new Sentence( verb, object, subject ) );
            }
        }

        for( String joint: ontology.getJoints() )
        {
            for( Integer subind: ontology.getSubjectIndices( joint ) )
            {
                Sentence xaS = ontology.getSentence( subind );

                for( Integer obind: ontology.getObjectIndices( joint ) )
                {

                    Sentence yOb = ontology.getSentence( obind );

                    Sentence s = new Sentence( xaS.getVerb(),
                                           xaS.getObject(),
                                           yOb.getSubject() );

                    ontology.numberRules( s );    

                }
            }
        }
    /**
     * This is an example call to the hypernym generating function
     * 
     * wordnet_interface.getHypernyms( "word" );        
     **/

    // this prints out each observed datum sentence once on the basis 
    // of how often it was seen in our corpus
    ontology.ruleCount.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 0 )
    .sorted(reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
    .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue()));

    }   
}
```

This is the `Ontology` class, which stores the sentence components in a hash map:

```
public class Ontology 
{

    private List<Sentence> sentences = new ArrayList<>();
    /*
     * The following maps store the relation of a string occurring
     * as a subject or object, respectively, to the list of Sentence
     * ordinals where they occur.
     */
    private Map<String,List<Integer>> subject2index = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<String,List<Integer>> object2index = new HashMap<>();

    /*
     * This set contains strings that occur as both,
     * subject and object. This is useful for determining strings
     * acting as an in-between connecting two relations. 
     */
    private Set<String> joints = new HashSet<>();

    public void addSentence( Sentence s )
    {
        sentences.add( s );

        /*
         * why do you call s.getSubject() if this is an integer 
         * value? wouldn't that return a string and not an 
         * integer? Oh, wait a minute... maybe this is a tricky form
         * of Hashmap key, whereby he renders the string as a number
         * and uses that as they key of the hashmap... clever. maybe. 
         */
        List<Integer> subind = subject2index.get( s.getSubject() );

        if( subind == null )
        {
            /*
             * So you have a list of integers named subind
             * and an ArrayList named subind?! are you
             * fucking kidding me?! That's so confusing!
             */
            subind = new ArrayList<>();
            subject2index.put( s.getSubject(), subind );
        }
        subind.add( sentences.size() - 1 );

        List<Integer> objind = object2index.get( s.getObject() );
        if( objind == null )
        {
            objind = new ArrayList<>();
            object2index.put( s.getObject(), objind );
        }
        objind.add( sentences.size() - 1 );

        if( subject2index.containsKey( s.getObject() ) )
        {
            joints.add( s.getObject() );
        }
        if( object2index.containsKey( s.getSubject() ) )
        {
            joints.add( s.getSubject() );
        }
    }

    public Collection<String> getJoints()
    {
        return joints;
    }
    public List<Integer> getSubjectIndices( String subject )
    {
        return subject2index.get( subject );
    }
    public List<Integer> getObjectIndices( String object )
    {
        return object2index.get( object );
    }
    public Sentence getSentence( int index )
    {
        return sentences.get( index );
    }


    //map to store learned 'rules'
    Map<Sentence, Integer> ruleCount = new HashMap<>();
    //store data
    public void numberRules(Sentence sentence) 
    {
        if (!ruleCount.containsKey(sentence))
        {
            ruleCount.put(sentence, 0);
        }
        ruleCount.put(sentence, ruleCount.get(sentence) + 1);
    }   
}
```

This is the Java Wordnet Interface holder:

```
public class MITJavaWordNetInterface 
{

    public void getHypernyms( String inut_word ) throws IOException
    {

        // construct the URL to the Wordnet dictionary directory
        String wnhome = System.getenv("WNHOME");
        String path = wnhome + File.separator + "dict";
        URL url = new URL ("file", null , path );

        // construct the dictionary object and open it
        IDictionary dict = new Dictionary ( url ) ;
        dict.open();


         // get the synset of 'input_word'
         IIndexWord idxWord = dict . getIndexWord (inut_word, POS . NOUN ) ;
         IWordID wordID = idxWord . getWordIDs () . get (0) ; // 1st meaning
         IWord word = dict . getWord ( wordID ) ;
         ISynset synset = word . getSynset () ;

         // get the hypernyms
         List < ISynsetID > hypernyms =
         synset . getRelatedSynsets ( Pointer . HYPERNYM ) ;

         // print out each h y p e r n y m s id and synonyms
         List < IWord > words ;
         for( ISynsetID sid : hypernyms ) {
         words = dict . getSynset ( sid ) . getWords () ;
         System . out . print ( sid + " {") ;
         for( Iterator < IWord > i = words . iterator () ; i . hasNext () ;) {
         System . out . print ( i . next () . getLemma () ) ;
         if( i . hasNext () )
         System . out . print (", ") ;
         }
         System . out . println ("}") ;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `main`

> ```
>     MITJavaWordNetInterface wordnet_interface = new MITJavaWordNetInterface();
> ```

You never actually use this.  You could just as well embed it in the comment:

```
    /**
     * This is an example call to the hypernym generating function
     * 
     * MITJavaWordNetInterface wordnet_interface = new MITJavaWordNetInterface();
     * wordnet_interface.getHypernyms( "word" );        
     **/
```

Now there are both an example declaration and use in the comment.

You do a lot of work in the `main` method.  Consider pushing some of that out into functions.  E.g.

```
private static Ontology readFile(String filename) throws IOException
{
    Ontology ontology = new Ontology();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'\\('(.*?)',\\s*'(.*?)'\\)\\.");
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        if ( m.matches() ) 
        {
            String verb    = m.group(1);
            String object  = m.group(2);
            String subject = m.group(3);
            ontology.addSentence( new Sentence( verb, object, subject ) );
        }
    }

    return ontology;
}

private static void makeInferences(Ontology ontology) {
    for( String joint: ontology.getJoints() )
    {
        for( Integer subjectIndex: ontology.getSubjectIndices( joint ) )
        {
            Sentence xaS = ontology.getSentence( subjectIndex );

            for( Integer objectIndex: ontology.getObjectIndices( joint ) )
            {

                Sentence yOb = ontology.getSentence( objectIndex );

                Sentence s = new Sentence( xaS.getVerb(),
                                       xaS.getObject(),
                                       yOb.getSubject() );

                ontology.numberRules( s );    

            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    Ontology ontology = readFile("file.txt");
    makeInferences(ontology);

    /**
     * This is an example call to the hypernym generating function
     * 
     * MITJavaWordNetInterface wordnet_interface = new MITJavaWordNetInterface();
     * wordnet_interface.getHypernyms( "word" );        
     **/

    // this prints out each observed datum sentence once on the basis 
    // of how often it was seen in our corpus
    ontology.ruleCount.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 0 )
    .sorted(reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
    .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue()));
}
```

I just made them members of `lets_go` (which I renamed to `Main`), but you could also put them in `Ontology` or a new class if you wanted.  I would tend to think that `makeInferences` should be in `Ontology` while `readFile` should be in a separate class, but it really depends on how you use them.  There's an argument that `addSentence` should handle making inferences in which case `makeInferences` would be redundant.

I wrote out `subjectIndex` and `objectIndex` to make it clearer what each represents.

What are `xaS` and `yOb`?  Longer, more descriptive names would make the logic easier to understand.

Notice how none of the variables defined in the first function are needed in the second (with the exception of `ontology` which is actually declared in `main`).  This is a big part of why I felt that they should be in separate functions.

Now `main` knows that it needs to read input and make inferences, but it doesn't need to know how to do those things.

### Ontology

> ```
>     /*
>      * why do you call s.getSubject() if this is an integer 
>      * value? wouldn't that return a string and not an 
>      * integer? Oh, wait a minute... maybe this is a tricky form
>      * of Hashmap key, whereby he renders the string as a number
>      * and uses that as they key of the hashmap... clever. maybe. 
>      */
> ```

This seems like this is not code that you wrote, so it would be off-topic for review.  As a general rule, you should answer questions like those posed here before sending the code out for review.  In particular, if you don't like variable names in code that you maintain, then why not change them?

### MITJavaWordNetInterface

Your indentation is inconsistent here.  A more typical form:

```
    // print out each h y p e r n y m s id and synonyms
    List < IWord > words;
    for ( ISynsetID sid : hypernyms ) {
        words = dict.getSynset( sid ).getWords();
        System.out.print( sid + " {");
        for ( Iterator< IWord > i = words.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            System.out.print( i.next().getLemma() );
            if ( i.hasNext() ) {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("}");
    }
```

It's much easier to see where each block begins this way.

Also note that I added curly brackets `{}` around the statement in the innermost `if`.  Not only does that make it clearer where one piece begins and the other ends, but it avoids a particularly nasty to debug issue where someone tries to add a second statement to an `if` form that only allows one.

It's a bit confusing to call this an `Interface`.  The term interface has a specific meaning in Java.  You might be better off calling it a Facade, an Adapter, or some other [Structural Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_pattern) name.

Comment: Eclipse, and I, don't understand how you can, seem to, instantiate Ontology and read one of it's methods in the same line. What's up with that?

Comment: If you made `readFile` a `static public` method on `Ontology`, you could say `Ontology ontology = Ontology.readFile("file.txt");`.